# Configure the connection_collation with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, collation

I'm attempting to get SQLAlchemy to connect to MySQL with a `collation_connection` of `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

My sever and database are both using the `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation. Without any configuration changes my `collation_connection` is `utf8_general_ci`. If I set the `charset` argument in the connection string to `charset=utf8mb4` the `collation_connection` is then set to `utf8mb4_general_ci`. I have been unable to find any documentation stating how to set the `collation_connection` when using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: The `collation_connection` has very little impact on things.  What issues have you encountered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a variable specific to mysql and all you can do is to run a statement on each connection initialization:

```
In [18]: url = 'mysql+pymysql://test:test@localhost/test'

In [19]: connect_args = {'init_command':"SET @@collation_connection='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'"}

In [20]: with sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, connect_args=connect_args).connect() as con:
    ...:     print(con.execute('select @@collation_connection;').fetchall())
    ...:
[('utf8mb4_unicode_ci',)]
```